# How to get the week number starting from monday of given month in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to calculate the week number starting from first Monday of October. Is there any functions in pandas or datetime to do the calculation efficiently?

## MWE

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date,datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2021-10-01','2022-11-01',freq='1D')})
df['day_name'] = df['date'].dt.day_name()

df2 = df.head()
df2['Fiscal_Week'] = [52,52,52,1,1] # 2021-10-4 is monday, so for oct4, week is 1
# How to do it programatically for any year?

df2
    date        day_name Fiscal_Week
0   2021-10-01  Friday   52
1   2021-10-02  Saturday 52
2   2021-10-03  Sunday   52
3   2021-10-04  Monday   1
4   2021-10-05  Tuesday  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shift dates by the number of days to new year, they use standard Monday week number formatting (`%W`):

```
df['Fiscal_Week'] = (
    df['date'] + pd.DateOffset(days=91)
).dt.strftime('%W').astype(int).replace({0:None}).fillna(method='ffill')
```

- The offset in days can be calculated manually (I assume the fiscal year start is fixed)
- The `replace` part is needed because leftovers from the previous year are considered week 0. The previous week might be 52 or 53, so replacing with `NA` and then fill forward

Comment: also, can we also get the `fiscal_year_start` similarly as the fist monday of october of given year? (`df['Fiscal_Year_Start'] = (
    df['date'] + pd.DateOffset(days=91)
).dt.strftime('%Y_%m_%d')`  not working for me.

Comment: @usermay14 yes, I'll add and example shortly

Comment: Also, why you have `days=91`?

Comment: @usermay14 I assumed fiscal year starts on a fixed day, like Oct 1 - thus, fixed number of days till the New Year to correct the week number. The current code is based on the assumption